# Searching a list and displaying whether or not the list contains the search variable

Tags: for-loop, for-else

I have a Twitter manager program where one option is searching for tweets containing whatever input the user provides. I am unable to figure out a way to have the for loop skip the else statement when there is a match found in the list. As it works now, the program will print the tweet it finds that matches the search criteria, but also prints that no tweet is found containing the search criteria.

```
# Option 3, search tweet_list for specific content and display if found
# in descending order starting with the most recent.
elif count == 3:
    tweet_list.reverse()
    if len(tweet_list) == 0:
        print('There are no tweets to search.', '\n')
    else:
        search = input('What would you like to search for? ')
        print('\nSearch Results')
        print('--------------')

        for n in tweet_list:
            a = n.get_author()
            b = n.get_text()
            c = n.get_age()

            if search in a or search in b:
                print(a + '-' + c + '\n' + b + '\n')                   

        else:
            print('No tweets contain "' + search + '".' + '\n')
            print('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable, say `found`, and initialize it to `False`.  When you find a tweet, set it to `True`.  Then replace the `else:` with `if not found:`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Replacing else: with if not found: didn't display the message if tweet wasn't found, but I changed it to if found == "False" and all seems to be working with your other changes.

Comment: When I mentioned `True` and `False`, I meant the boolean values; it appears that you used strings instead, which is why you needed to change the test.

Comment: Oh I follow you now. I'm a novice so thank you again for your help!